# Internet speed tests show fast download speeds, but "real-world" download speeds are significantly slower

Tags: networking, internet, isp, internet-speed

Before we begin, I would like to clarify that I am aware that internet speed is measured in Mb/s (mega**bits** per second) while most applications show download speeds in MB/s (mega**bytes** per second), and that 8 Mb == 1 MB. This is not the issue.

Some information:

- I am sharing a home network with 3 other users.
- I have tested everything on both wi-fi and wired connections.
- I have tested from every device on my home network, each device gives the same results.
- I have tried using a VPN.
- This happens at all times of the day (weekdays, weekends, early mornings, midday, late afternoons, etc.)
- My ISP is [WOW!](https://www.wowway.com/). As far as I can tell, they have no data caps and do not throttle download speeds.
- I have checked my router settings. It doesn't have very many in the first place, and there are no unnecessary options enabled.

Every internet speed test I try ([sponsored](http://wowway.speedtestcustom.com/) and [independent](https://testmy.net/)) show that each device on my home network has ~50 Mb/s download speed. My router also lets me perform a speed test directly from itself, and it shows ~200 Mb/s download speed, which is what I am paying for. With these results, I should be getting around ~5 MB/s download speeds, but I would usually get 2-3 MB/s before this problem, and that was plenty for me.

This past week or so, it has been a pain to download large (> 100 MB) files. Whenever I download a large file, there seems to be a short burst of high download speeds in the first 1-2 seconds, and then it dwindles all the way down to <500 KB/s. Looking this phenomenon up on the internet, I found that this short burst of high download speeds on new connections is a clever trick ISP's use to allow websites to load quickly, making users feel like their internet speeds are faster than they might be paying for. This explains why I can browse the web quickly, but downloading large files is very slow.

With that in mind, is it possible that my ISP is throttling all of my connections except for connections to speed tests?

Before I call my ISP, are there other things I can do to investigate this problem?

Comment: There can be speed limitations from the server you are downloading from..  Have you tried from a computer on some other ISP, e.g a computer at a library? And have you tried downloading a big file from other servers? e.g. Try using the yt-dlp command https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp.exe   to download a youtube video  e.g.  save yt-dlp.exe to c:\blah, then open cmd and do `cd \blah`  then from the blah directory, do `C:\blah>yt-dlp https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e2Sv0BYyfi0` that video is 1.5min but you can try for longer ones.

Comment: @barlop I know that internet speeds are only as fast as the weakest link in the network, but I have a problem downloading large files from *anywhere*. This includes Linux distribution ISO's, any large program installers (Visual Studio literally takes days to download), and yes, videos as well. I live in the country, so I am unfortunately not able to test your idea of trying another ISP.

Comment: do reach out to your ISP. given that most speedtests show a quarter of your advertised rate, they should be able to help you, and they have visibility into issues that no one else can observe, like billing codes, local infrastructure capacity, low signal-to-noise, etc.

Comment: I had a similar issue with my Unify Security Gateway.  I had turned on threat management, not realizing that this reduced the throughput drastically.  So, have a look at your router settings.

Comment: @FrankThomas I'm fairly certain my router equally dishes out bandwidth according to the number of devices actively using the internet (up to 4 in my case, hence a quarter of the total rate per device), so it doesn't concern me that speed tests from my devices show only a quarter of the rate I'm paying for. The important one is the speed test conducted directly from the router, which shows that I should be getting the download speeds I am paying for, so I really don't want to suspect my ISP. That said, is there really nothing else I can do?

Comment: @RohitGupta My router doesn't have very many configuration options, and there are no unnecessary options enabled.

Comment: no your router does not reserve bandwidth for devices, so any one device on your network should be able to use the full bandwidth available. it would only be as you describe if all 4 devices were actively using exactly 50Mb/s at the same time. So last year i had a problem where at 4-5PM every day, my internet would barely work. tech support eventually realized I had low SNR, and sent a guy out. after testing all the inside lines, he checked the pole, and replaced 6' of the drop to the house that had spontaneously gone bad. problem solved. they'd never have known if I didn;t call though.

Comment: @FrankThomas a)I am not sure i'd rule out the possibility that there could be a fault with the router.. b)your issue is not equivalent unless your attempt at a web speed test said all was good

Comment: oh I completely agree the router may well be the culprit, and QOS quotas are a possibility, but not a common thing for an ISP to configure. and I'm not implying that the issue is equivalent, just that it was something only the ISP could diagnose and resolve, and that if I hadn't reached out to them I never would have gotten a resolution. I've had issues with billing codes before, where parts of the ISP system thought I had one set of entitlements, and other parts of their network disagreed. These kinds of issues can only be found by the ISP, so I think op should engage with them in parallel.